# ¿En qué casos un prefijo añadido a un verbo cambia su conjugación?

Tags: verbos, conjugación, prefijos, formas-irregulares

Muchos hemos tenido dudas al conjugar el futuro de algún verbo como "maldecir". De que es algo habitual da fe la [página del DPD al respecto](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=maldecir).

Y es casi, pero no igual, a la conjugación de "decir".

> Verbo irregular: se conjuga como *decir* (→ [apéndice
>   1](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/apendices/apendice1.html), [n.º
>   28](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/apendices/apendice1.html#n28)), salvo en el
>   futuro simple o futuro de indicativo y en el condicional simple o
>   pospretérito, cuyas formas son regulares: *maldeciré*, *maldecirás*,
>   *maldecirá*, etc. y *maldeciría*, *maldecirías*, *maldeciría*, etc.; y en la segunda persona del imperativo no voseante, que es *maldice*
>   (tú).

¿Hay más casos como este, en el que la adición de un prefijo cambia la conjugación del verbo resultante? Si es así y, aunque sospecho que no, ¿hay alguna regla?

Comment: A partir del mismo verbo _decir_ se da lo mismo en _predecir - predeciré_, pero no en _contradecir - contradiré_ ni _desdecir - desdiré_.

Comment: Si, luego he pensado que había otros derivados de _decir_, pero no parece que las conjugaciones sean consistentes ni con él. Veremos si aparecen casos con otro verbo para comparar.

Comment: Yo personalmente suelo tener dudas con *predecir, conjugar*.  *Conjugar* y *jugar* parece que son bien diferentes.  Con *predecir*, no sé, la verdad.

Comment: @aparente001 *conjugar* parece ser versión prefijada de jugar, pero *jugar* viene del antiguo *iocare*, y conjugar de *con + iogare*.  No obstante, *predecir*, *contradecir*, *desdecir*, *bendecir* todos vienen del mismo *dicere* (*decir*)

Answer (score 3):

| Dipthongizes when conjugated | Vowel unchanged |
| --- | --- |
| tender <sub>(t**ie**ndo)</sub> | pretender <sub>(pret**e**ndo)</sub> |
| rogar <sub>(r**ue**go)</sub> | abrogar, arrogar, derogar, interrogar, prorrogar, subrogar <sub>(abr**o**go etc)</sub> |

And the following, which have different conjugations for different prefixes:

| Dipthongizes when conjugated | Vowel unchanged |
| --- | --- |
| defender <sub>(def**ie**ndo)</sub> | ofender <sub>(of**e**ndo)</sub> |
| confesar <sub>(conf**ie**so)</sub> | profesar <sub>(prof**e**so)</sub> |
| desterrar <sub>(dst**ie**rro)</sub> | aterrar* <sub>(at**e**rro)</sub> |

---

<sub>* aterrar cognate with *terror*, not aterrar cognate with *tierra*.</sub>
<sub>Source: Spanish Verbs Made Simple(r) (p.27)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Los verbos irregulares tienen 3 modelos de conjugación, pero no es posible decir que respeten un modelo por alguna regla en especial, es por esto que son irregulares, el uso y las propiedades de la variación de la lengua los convierten en alguno de los tres modelos. Podría darse el caso que mencionás donde sería posible intentar inducir alguna regla por etimología de la raíz, pero eso puede ser simple casualidad.

Habiendo dicho esto, en mi estudio, como opinión personal, prefiero no utilizar el modo que tiene la R.A.E. de citar los modelos de conjugación irregular (-se conjuga como "x infinitivo"-) y utilizar los tres modelos conocidos.

Comment: @Alicia, la pregunta supone que existe una relación entre la raíz y la conjugación irregular, la cual en realidad no existe ya que cada verbo, aunque esté compuesto de un prefijo (discutible qué es un prefijo en un verbo y qué no lo es), responde a un modelo particular de conjugación irregular, y he ahí mi respuesta.

Comment: @MacGyver No supongo ninguna relación entre la raíz y la conjugación irregular. ¿Qué frase de mi pregunta te induce a creerlo? Si me muestras que hay algo confuso o ambiguo no dudaré en cambiar el enunciado de la pregunta.

Comment: Hola @cdlvcdlv, es bueno tu comentario y por eso lo voto. Pues creo que en la pregunta misma, porque al caso podríamos afirmar ¿en qué casos no cambia? Lo que advierto con mi respuesta, es que no puede ser respondida en forma tal, o en otra lógica, cambia en todos los casos, ya que son irregulares y por tanto tienen comportamientos de otros verbos, salvo que en ciertos casos da la casualidad de que coincide el o los modelos de conjugación irregular (recordemos que son tres modelos aditivos). Quizá lo discutible se basa en si existen verbos con "prefijos" si se han convertido en irregulares.

Comment: @MacGyver ¿Podrías documentar tu respuesta? La RAE dice que [hay 47 modelos de conjugación irregular](https://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/modelos-de-conjugacion-verbal#verirreg) (bueno, 46 quitando _leer_, que lo es según), no 3. En todo caso, tu respuesta parece más un comentario.

Comment: Los tres modelos de conjugación irregular aditiva (en la combinatoria pueden ser más de 50) se pueden encontrar en muchas obras de estudio de gramática española, obviamente mucho mejores que las de la RAE que son de referencia, no de estudio, ya que la RAE no dicta norma. Obviamente desde Samuel Gili Gaya hasta cualquier autor, mi recomendación personal es "Gramática Moderna del Español, Teoría y Norma" de M. J. Sanchez Marquez

Comment: @MacGyver Es interesante eso que cuentas, aunque mi pregunta era sobre _diferencias_ entre los verbos con y sin prefijo. De todas formas, si crees que esos tres modelos son relevantes a la pregunta, deberías **mostrarlo** en tu respuesta. Alguna cita de los textos usados sería necesaria y una referencia consultable en Internet, miel sobre hojuelas. Nadie tiene por qué saber cuáles son esos tres modelos a los que te refieres ni cómo se combinan.